# GridLayout to fit buttons in the screen

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to put three buttons horizontally. I approached via using Grid and I could able to see them properly in Samsung Galaxy 4, but when I test it in smaller screen the buttons does not fit into screen, the last button is cut.

```
   <GridLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancelPost"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/Cancel"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonResetPost"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/Reset"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmitPost"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/post"/>
    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
You need to create different layouts for different screen sizes. 
I do not think there is a layout that automatically adapts the components .

Answer (score 0):

The 3 buttons combined width is exceeding the screens width thats why the last none gets cut.try decreasing the buttons layout_width until they all fit ..or try vertical arrangement if you don't mind.

the button text property also adds to the buttons size , something to consider.